# Create link to a Facebook photo album starting with newest photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

We use frequently updated Facebook albums to sort images of multiple projects. We would like to create links to the new photos, but have only been able to link either a) to the entire album, starting with the oldest photos, or b) to a specific photo, hoping that people will know to click through the rest of the album that doesn't appear.

Does anyone know a way to link directly to the timeline post that just says "new photos were added to xxxxxxxxxxxx album"? This would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you snagging the URL right from the profile? Or where exactly are you looking to search for the link from.  If you go to your profile / timeline, paste this code into the javascript console (or remove all spaces and throw it after 'javascript:' in the URL) it will load the url...

```
var fillArray = [];
var timelinePosts = document.getElementsByClassName("timelineUnitContainer");
for(var i = 0; i < timelinePosts.length; i++) {
    try {
        var tmp = timelinePosts[i].dataset["gt"].toLowerCase().indexOf('statusmessageunit');
        if(tmp > -1) {
            fillArray.push(timelinePosts[i].getElementsByClassName("uiLinkSubtle")[0].href);
        }
    } catch(e) {
    //do nothing;
    }
}
window.location = fillArray[0];
```

Let me know how exactly you are trying to accomplish this